# How to subtract a column of values with another column of values?

Tags: perl, awk

I have two files with one column of values, like attachments below. I want to subtract the first value of file2 with all values in file1, these subtractions fill the first column in the output file, and then second value of file2 with all values in file1 ...

The output would look like this:

```
 -4(2-6)    -5    0    1
  0(2-2)    -1    4    5
 -2(2-4)    -3    2    3
 -3(2-5)    -4    1    2
 -6(2-8)    -7   -2   -1
```

Expressions in brackets in first column are only for explanation use and need to be discarded in output.

Also, the number of values in the column can vary.

Many thanks!

```
file1        file2

   6           2          
   2           1          
   4           6          
   5           7          
   8
```

Comment: Your shown examples are NOT clear, please mention more clear examples in your post.

Comment: please show what you tried

Comment: This still doesn't look any clearer than your attempt at asking this yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169847/how-to-subtract-a-value-with-a-column-of-values

Comment: @Chris: The question is slightly different: yesterday we were asked to do math with _one_ column in _two_ files, today it is _two_ columns in _one_ file.

Comment: @PerlDuck however the data is stored, neither of them were very clear questions

Comment: Don't repost questions! Youi posted the exactly same question yesterday (hence closure as dupe). This is against site-rules.

Comment: @fedorqui: FYI, the question you closed this as a dupe of is gone now.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen oh, that's a weirdy, edge case your SOUP may have encountered! Reopening then, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @fedorqui: Thanks! [I've got almost 1600 more](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209965/duplicates-of-deleted-questions), if you feel like lending a hand. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, then

```
awk 'NR == FNR { src[FNR] = $1; next } { for(i = 1; i <= length(src); ++i) { printf("%d\t", src[i] - $1); } print ""; }' file2 file1
```

produces the desired output. This works as follows:

```
NR == FNR {                             # while the first file (file2) is read:
  src[FNR] = $1                         # remember the numbers in an array
  next                                  # and we're done
}
{                                       # after that (when processing file1):
  for(i = 1; i <= length(src); ++i) {   # loop through the saved numbers
    printf("%d\t", src[i] - $1)         # subtract the current number from it,
                                        # print result followed by tab
  }
  print ""                              # when done, print a newline
}
```

**EDIT:** Since the question was edited to use one file with two columns instead of two with one each: The code can be slightly tweaked for that scenario as follows:

```
awk 'NR == FNR && NF > 1 { src[FNR] = $2 } NR != FNR && $1 != "" { for(i = 1; i <= length(src); ++i) { printf("%d\t", src[i] - $1); } print ""; }' file file
```

This follows the same basic pattern: Two passes are done over the file, one in which the numbers of the second column are saved and another in which the output is calculated and printed. The main addition is handling for empty fields:

```
NR == FNR && NF > 1 {                    # If this is the first pass and there is
  src[FNR] = $2                          # a second field, remember it
}
NR != FNR && $1 != "" {                  # If this is the second pass and there is
  for(i = 1; i <= length(src); ++i) {    # a first field, process it as before.
    printf("%d\t", src[i] - $1)
  }
  print ""
}
```

Alternatively, it could be done in one pass as follows:

```
awk '$1 != "" { a[NR] = $1 } NF > 1 { b[NR] = $2 } END { for(i = 1; i <= length(b); ++i) { for(j = 1; j <= length(a); ++j) { printf("%d\t", b[i] - a[j]) } print "" } }' file
```

That is:

```
$1 != "" { a[NR] = $1 }                # If there is a first field, remember it
NF > 1   { b[NR] = $2 }                # If there is a second field, remember it
END {                                  # After reaching the end of the file,
  for(i = 1; i <= length(b); ++i) {    # process the saved data as before.
    for(j = 1; j <= length(a); ++j) {
      printf("%d\t", b[i] - a[j])
    }
    print ""
  }
}
```

Comment: This is actually an answer to [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49169847/5830574), not to the current one. The current question deals with two columns in one file, i.e. there is no file1 and file2.

Comment: @PerlDuck The question was edited after the answer was posted. Since OP accepted the answer, I suspect the edit was erroneous, but I suppose I'll add something for it.